# Moving row data towards the front of row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a macro using VBA to move my row cell values to the front if there are blank cells in between but can't seem to work it out.

Example:

**Sample Input**

[image: Raw data table]

**Sample Output**

[image: Desired output data table]

I need the code to move the values in the second row to the front (nearest to the left) if there is a blank cell in between. For instance, there is a blank cell in Column 2, and there is a '5' value in Column 3. So I would need to move the '5' to Column 2, and the same for the '8' value in Column 7 that would need to be moved behind the '5' in Column 3.

I appreciate the help! PS: I'm still learning the ropes of VBA, so some description/documentation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells), select the blank cells and delete them, shifting left. (you can do this manually and use the macro recorder to get most of the relevant code).

Comment: Thank you for your help! That works well in 365, going to try it in 2016 soon. Will update you on the outcome!